# Get/Modify single entries in non-contiguous submatrix views

Tags: armadillo

I would like to access and modify single entries in a non-contiguous submatrix view. I tried it like this:

```
#include <armadillo>    // version 5.200.2

int main()
{
    arma::mat A(4, 4, arma::fill::zeros);

    arma::uvec b(4);
    b << 2 << 3;

    auto view = A.elem(b, b);
    view(0, 0) = 1.0;       // Error: No operator()
}
```

This doesn't work because the expression returned by A.elem(b, b) appears to have no operator() defined. I found that the same thing works with contiguous views like e.g. submat(). Is there any solution/workaround for this or is it simply not possible in the non-contiguous case?

Comment: Possible workaround: set the elements in a temporary matrix, and then copy it to the non-contiguous matrix. For example: `A.elem(b,b) = tmp`. Also using `auto` with Armadillo expressions is not a good idea, as they're composed of short-lived temporaries.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably do it like this.